# crontab not executing perl script

Tags: perl, path, cron, raspberry-pi, environment-variables

I'm having issues scheduling a crontab task; I have googled and read tons of pages but can't understand if the solutions given are example specific and they don't seem to fix my issue.

I'm trying to run a basic perl script called `perl_speedtest.pl` which lives in the `/home/pi/Documents/Projects` directory on my raspberry pi. When I run the script manually by command: `perl perl_speedtest.pl` from the above directory it works perfect.

I have scheduled the task to run every 20 minutes with the following crontab job by using the 'crontab -e' command in the terminal:

```
*/20 * * * * perl /home/pi/Documents/Projects/perl_speedtest.pl
```

for some reason this doesn't execute.. any ideas? Happy to share more details if needed.

Comment: You should define [email address](https://serverfault.com/questions/54152/how-to-get-e-mail-from-failed-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu) in **crontab** file and you will receive email with error/result of an attempt to run the script. [man crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) It will help you to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Please try to specify full path to **perl** something like **/usr/bin/perl**. Crontab environment is different from your own, path to perl may be not included in PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

Set your environment in `cron` correctly as the commenters above point out. Otherise, `cron` uses a pretty minimal environment (including `PATH`, `PERL5LIB`, etc). Your `crontab` should look something like this, depending on your actual environment as you use it in your interactive shell:

```sh
HOME=/home/pi
SHELL=/bin/bash
MAIL=/usr/bin/mail

06 */1 * * * source ~/.bashrc &> /dev/null ; perl /home/pi/Documents/Projects/perl_speedtest.pl

# or this (find the perl path by executing "which perl"):

06 */1 * * * /usr/bin/perl /home/pi/Documents/Projects/perl_speedtest.pl
```

Comment: `.bashrc` is for *interactive* shells, so that first version isn't good. The login script used by bash is actually the first of `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. Fixed:`06 */1 * * * exec /bin/bash -lc '"$@"' x perl /home/pi/Documents/Projects/perl_speedtest.pl`

Comment: `*/1` what does that do ?

Comment: @Red it's a "step value" (see `man 5 crontab`) but since it's a "1" it's the same as just `*`